# Sudo can not find binary

Tags: linux, sudo, bashrc

I have a problem.

Lately I've installed `nodejs` (if you don't know what it is, it does not really matter, could be anything else) from sources to /opt/node:

```
$ ls -la /opt
...
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   11 2012-07-25 13:48 node -> node-0.6.3/
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 2012-07-25 13:48 node-0.6.3
...
```

so, the binaries are in `/opt/node/bin`:

```
$ ls -la /opt/node/bin
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      38 2012-06-20 11:44 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
...
```

As you can see, `npm` is there.
To make it easier to use it from a command line I fixed `$PATH` inside `.bashrc` script:

`HOME=$HOME:...:/opt/node/bin`

and so did to the root's `.bashrc`:

```
# which npm
/opt/node/bin/npm
```

But if I run npm with sudo, `npm` is not found:

```
$ sudo which npm
$ sudo npm -g install uglify-js
sudo: npm: command not found
```

So, why is it happening? How do I gain what I want?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Following Paul's advice, I've added

```
Defaults  env_keep = PATH
```

to the `/etc/sudoers`

but the problem persists anyway:

```
$ echo $PATH
... :/opt/node/bin
$ sudo su -
#
# sudo -V
...
Environment variables to preserve:
    XAUTHORIZATION
    XAUTHORITY
    TZ
    PS2
    PS1
    PATH
...
```

So, `Defaults` directive did it's job, but I'm getting the same `sudo: npm: command not found`

Comment: So you marked an answer as accepted, but it did not fix your problem?

Comment: It did. Why you think it didn't ?

Comment: Related: [Why are PATH variables different when running via sudo and su?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8646/21471) at Unix SE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sudo` invokes a new shell, and the environmental variables that are passed to the new shell are governed by the '/etc/sudoers' file.  If you want your path to be passed through, then you need to add

```
Defaults env_keep = "PATH"
```

to '/etc/sudoers' and it will keep the PATH environment variable in the sudo shell

If this does not work, it is possible that either the path is being overwritten by a `secure_path` directive (sometime a secure_path is compiled in to the binary).  If so, try adding this command, replacing the groupname with a group you are a member of:

```
exempt_group = "groupname"
```

Or override the secure_path with your own one, eg:

```
secure_path = "/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/node/bin"
```

Comment: Thank you for a reply. It seems to be the key, but it does not make a difference. See above the update section of my question.

Comment: Can you add a `sudo env | grep PATH` to the question?

Comment: @Nemoden just a ping as I left you off the previous comment

Comment: Path to /opt/node/bin is not in `sudo env | grep PATH`: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin`

Comment: @Nemoden Answer updated

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem -> mine was caused by `npm` being install in `/use/local/bin`.

And I had this line in my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Typing which `npm` was the enlightening part :)